# How to update all your apps from the Android market over web?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, application-autoupdate, web-market

I constantly get multiple update notifications on my Android phone.  How do I go online from my computer and update all my applications to my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to go through your library, find each app that had an update, and then select to install it from the website. There is no way to batch update your apps from the web Market.